# Why does changing the order of including psapi.h gives compilation erros?(Indentifier BOOL is undefined)

Tags: c++, windows, psapi

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 to code c++. When I run the following code everything works fine.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include<Windows.h>
#include<Psapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Really!! How do you do it?";
    _getch();
}
```

But if I change the order of `#include`s by including `psapi.h` before `Windows.h`, compiler goes badass and throws 198 errors at me, which surprisingly(maybe only to me) includes **Identifier "BOOL" is undefined**.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Probably because `Psapi.h` needs some definitions made in `Windows.h` like `BOOL`?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, did you see where `BOOL` is defined and why this would need to be defined prior to it's usage?

Comment: `Psapi.h` should include `Windows.h` itself to avoid such problems.

Comment: The author(s) of psapi.h seem to have fostered an header file *order  dependency*, which frankly is just wrong. It's not your fault. The only header psapi.h internally includes is winapifamily.h, which itself does *not* include windows.h, windef.h, etc, any number of which would pull in the proper macros/typedefs for dependent use within psapi (like BOOL, WINAPI, etc). If there's a reason the author(s) did this outside of flat-out laziness or oversight, I can't think of it. You'll have to include it yourself prior to psapi.h

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since *Psapi.h*'s include tree is trivial, I'm going to exemplify. 
Everything relies on ***VStudio 2015*** (Community) (*v14.0.25431.01 Update 3*) and ***Windows Kits 8.1*** (? funny, because *v10* is there too) files (with default env vars and preprocessor definitions):

- *BOOL* is defined in *minwindef.h* (***#157***: `typedef int                 BOOL;`)
- *Psapi.h* only includes one file (***#27***: `#include <winapifamily.h>`)

  - *winapifamily.h* doesn't include any other file

So, when reaching *Psapi.h* (***#87***: `BOOL WINAPI EnumProcesses (...`), the compiler doesn't know anything about *BOOL*, so it complains.

*Windows.h* **includes** *minwindef.h* (indirectly, via *windef.h*), and that's why it works when you include it before *Psapi.h*.

Personally, I think it's a bug in *Psapi.h*, since it's not *self contained*, but there might be a good reason (that I'm not aware of) for that. 
Anyway, if this is indeed a bug, it wouldn't be *MS*'s 1<sup>st</sup> one :)

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>

// main present just for rigorosity's sake
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to answer the question, I know this is DATED but the issues persist today. You need the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <psapi.h>
```

After stdlib.h was included, the errors were gone.